# How to handle DNS timeouts with aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The [aiohttp readme](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/README.rst#getting-started) says:

> If you want to use timeouts for aiohttp client please use standard asyncio approach:
>   yield from asyncio.wait_for(client.get(url), 10)

But that doesn't handle DNS timeouts which are, I guess, handled by the OS. Also the `with aiohttp.Timeout` doesn't handle OS DNS lookups.

There has been a discussion at the [asyncio repo](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/160) without final conclusion and Saghul has made [aiodns](https://github.com/saghul/aiodns) but I'm not sure how to mix it into aiohttp and whether that will allow `asyncio.wait_for` functionality.

Testcase (takes 20 sec on my linux box):

```
async def fetch(url):
    url = 'http://alicebluejewelers.com/'
    with aiohttp.Timeout(0.001):
        resp = await aiohttp.get(url)
```

Answer (score 5):

`Timeout` works as expected but unfortunately your example hangs on python shutdown procedure: it waits for termination of background thread which performs DNS lookup.

As a solution I can suggest using `aiodns` for manual IP resolving:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import aiodns

async def fetch():
    dns = 'alicebluejewelers.com'
    # dns = 'google.com'
    with aiohttp.Timeout(1):
        ips = await resolver.query(dns, 'A')
        print(ips)
        url = 'http://{}/'.format(ips[0].host)
        async with aiohttp.get(url) as resp:
            print(resp.status)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
resolver = aiodns.DNSResolver(loop=loop)
loop.run_until_complete(fetch())
```

Maybe solution worth to be included into TCPConnector as optional feature.

Pull Request is welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! It has two issues though, the http host header needs to be set (trivial I guess) and ssl verification will fail. Will look into it and keep you posted.

Comment: For Googlers, this has been implemented in aiohttp: see https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/pull/819